# slow down scrolling adjustment when selecting a long line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a long line that I want to select a section in the middle. In Visual Studio, it would scroll all the way to the end of the line, passing where I want the selection to end, when I move pass the text area and move all the way back when I try to move back a little. Is there a way to slow down the Visual Studio scrolling adjustment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about selecting text using the mouse you can get fine grained control by combining the the mouse and keyboard.  This should work in any application that allows text selection, not just Visual Studio.

First click the location where you want to begin selecting text.
Next scroll to the location where you want to end selecting text and hold down Shift on the keyboard while clicking with the mouse.  The block of text between the first click and the shift+click will be selected without having to worry about the selection jumping around due to scrolling.

As for actually slowing down the scrolling; I know of no way to do that.  Hopefully my tip should give you an alternate way to do what you actually want.